# In Stata, make a binary factor variable out of a 6-level factor variable

Tags: stata, data-cleaning

I'm trying to turn a six-level categorical variable into a two-level categorical variable. I'm not so familiar with Stata and every way I've tried this yields an error.

Here's the original variable, `var`, and how it's currently coded. The variable is from a questionnaire asking how often something happened.

```
once = 1
twice = 2
three times = 3
four times = 4
five times = 5
never = 6
```

What I want is a binary variable that collapses 1 through 5 into "1", and makes "never" as "0":

```
once = 1
twice = 1
three times = 1
four times = 1
five times = 1
never = 0
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
  gen H3MA3_bin = H3MA3
  recode H3MA3_bin (1==1) (2==1) (3==1) (4==1) (5==1) (6==0)
```

This yields the error: `unknown el == in rule`

Comment: The error is using == not = but there is no need to spell out all the possibilities,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  gen wanted = var < 6 if var < .
```

Comment: This works! Thank! But: why do I not need to spell out the "1" and "0" bits? How does Stata know?

Comment: See Stata FAQ on true and false. I will add the link later if you can’t find it.

Comment: https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/ is the link regardless.